# Overriding signals and alternate functions

Tags: microcontroller, datasheet

I am new into microcontroller and had started going into the Atmega328p datasheet. I had a confusion regarding the Overriding signals and overriding functions. As far as I understood the overriding signals are general for all the ports (don't know if I'm right) while for each port we have alternate functions. There are the two tables given. I am having difficulty in how these are linked. Kindly help me.
[image]
and

[image]

Link: [Atmega328p](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-8154-8-bit-avr-atmega16a_datasheet.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first table is about how an IO pin is interfaced by an alternate functionality.

The second table is about which IO pins have which alternate functionality and which signals drive the IO pin to go into alternate mode.

For example, if you enable Output Compare 1A feature, it will override the PB1 pin forcibly as output and the data to come from the timer compare bit.

Comment: so this just tells about the behaviour of each pin?